Desearía saber que es MVVM en WPF Quiero valorar si me resultaría útil en una aplicación que estoy desarrollando
¿Necesitaría comprender que es el modelo MVVM en aplicaciones WPF? ¿Para que sirve? ¿Hay alguna contraindicación con ADO.NET? ¿Un buen libro? Muchísimas gracias

Te respondo en orden: (1) si .- (2) Principalmente para hacer binding, que es un enlace entre los datos y la UI. Digamos que tienes un dato y un textbox, la forma "clasica" es textbox.text = dato para cargarlo (y lo inverso para obtener el dato) y esto lo repites por cada uno de los componentes. En cambio, con el binding, enlazas y los tus datos están representados automáticamente en la UI y cada modificación se refleja automáticamente y con validación de tipos incluida. Cuando comienzas a hacer esto inevitablemente necesitaras un modelo que sea un reflejo de la UI (modelo-vista) ...(cont)

Además, tendrás la vista (el XAML y su code behind [CB]) y te faltaría el modelo que en muchos casos viene a ser casi el modelo de datos (o una abstracción de él).- (3) No, pero te recomiendo EF).- (4) Para partir cualquiera, microsoft tiene algunos gratis. Un poco de historia: Cuando empezó esto del MVVM los desarrolladores se volvieron locos intentando cumplir con este patrón al 120%, competían por dejar el CB más limpio (porque no entendían que el CB es parte de la vista) y al final trabajaban más y complicaban todo, así que como todo patrón se debe usar mientras facilite la vida

MVVM es una arquitectura. Podrías aplicarla dónde quieras, en especial si ya existe soporte. Cómo es el caso de Android que tiene clases llamadas ViewModel y se puede integrar fácilmente en tu aplicación. Si no equivoco la forma tradicional de desarrollar en Android empleaba MVP (otra arquitectura similar).

Hola rlopez, tu pregunta va a ser cerrada, porque esta basada en opiniones y pide recomendaciones... por suerte, te contestaron en los comentarios, te lloveran votos negativos, cuando veas que la cierran, solo eliminala, y los votos desaparecen.

MVVM hace referencia a un patrón de diseño de software. Los patrones de software son formas ya definidas para resolver problemas específicos.
MVVM en inglés se refiere a Model-View-ViewModel, en español sería algo como Modelo-Vista-VistaModelo.
Este patrón resuelve el problema de cómo se debe comunicar el modelo (Model) y la Vista (View), ellos se comunican por medio de un ViewModel (VistaModelo).  Este patrón es abstracto, es decir no te dice como se debe escribir el código, sino simplemente te indica que cosas deben cumplirse.
Por lo anterior, existen diferentes implementaciones en código para MVVM. Por ejemplo:

ReactiveUI https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/
MvvMLight descontinuado https://www.mvvmlight.net/
MvvMTookit (renombrado a CommunityToolkit.Mvvm)   https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet

Cada uno ayuda a implementar MVVM y otros patrones complementarios. MVVM es solo un patrón común en WPF, pero hay mucho más conceptos y patrones relacionados que son de uso común en aplicaciones WPF. Por ejemplo, MVVM para WPF es normal utilizar Bindings (existen varios tipos de bidings), en ocasiones se utilizan Ruteadores (Routers), localizador de VistaModelos (ViewModel Locator), Inyección de Dependencias (Dependency Injection), Patrón de diseño Command (Command Pattern). Además de conceptos específicos de WPF, plantillas (Templates), estilos (Styles).

¿Para que sirve?

Define las reglas con las cuales la Vista (View) y el Modelo (Model) se comunican por medio de un VistaModelo (ViewModel). Para darte un ejemplo,

Una Vista (View) para ingresar credenciales podría tener:

Campo de texto (TextBox) para nombre de usuario (username)
Campo de texto (Textbox) para la contraseña (password)
Botón (Button) para Ingresar.


Un modelo (Model) de usuario posiblemente podría tener:

Identificación (Id)
Primer nombre (first name)
Primer Apellido (last name)
Contraseña desmenuzada (Hashed Password)
Fecha Creación (CreationDate)
.... etc



Como se puede notar el modelo (Model) tiene mucha más información de la que la vista no necesita. Y aun así, hay información que la Vista podría necesitar y que ese modelo no provee, por ejemplo, información como el título de la página de log in, o saber si boton de ingresar tiene que estar activo (Enabled) o inactivo (Disabled).
Aquí es donde viene el VistaModel (ViewModel) al rescate, el VistaModel (ViewModel) va a comunicarse con la vista y solo intercambiar la información que se necesita. Para nuestro ejemplo, solo necesitamos Nombre usuario (username), contraseña (Password), una bandera que nos diga si podemos hacer click en Ingresar (por ejemplo, esta bandera evitaría que hagamos click si el password está vacío, si el nombre de usuario está vacío, o si el password no cumple las reglas de validación). Por último, la VistaModel (ViewModel) podría exponer funcionalidad que se encarga de iniciar el proceso de validación de credenciales.
Al tener aislados los datos y comportamientos del log in nos da ciertas ventas.

Normalmente es más simple hacer pruebas unitarias de un VistaModelo (ViewModel) que de un View. Por ejemplo, existen muchos frameworks que podrías utilizar para pruebas unitarias de código C#, pero no muchos para pruebas automatizadas de WPF.
Los VistaModelo (ViewModels) podría ser reutilizables, por ejemplo si fuera un Vista Modelo para mostrar la inforamción de un usuario. Bastaría con crear una instancia de un ViewModel nuevo con datos diferentes y no hay necesita de cambiar la vista (View)
El código que es especifico de la vista (por ejemplo colores, animaciones, etc) no tiene que cambiar si cambiamos la lógica de como se validan las contraseñas. Esto porque La vista solo debería tener código relacionar al dibujo, el VistaModelo solo tiene código de comunicación con la vista. Y si el modelo (de datos) cambia, para la mayoría de los casos nuestro VistaModelo (ViewModel) permanece igual.


¿Hay alguna contraindicación con ADO.NET?

ADO.NET es un API para acceder bases de datos. En principio no tiene relación con MVVM.

¿Un buen libro? Muchísimas gracias

En mi opinión primero debe entender conceptos de WPF, como Binding, Templates, Commands, Styles, Resources, ...
Para luego conceptos más complejos como: Dependency Injection, Reactive Programming, etc.
Quizá la documentación de Microsoft sea un buen punto de partida https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/desktop/wpf/?view=netdesktop-8.0
En específico para el MVVM (explicacón para MAUI, pero igual es la parta abstracta)
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm
Aquí para WPF
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern
Muchos éxitos!
